# Is it possible to revisit cities?

Tags: dishonored

Is it possible to revisit cities to gather some money, find paintings you forgot to take or do whatever you'd like to do? I forgot to take one painting in the second mission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redo entire missions, but it's an all or nothing proposition. You cannot go back to a previously cleared area 'as you left it' to do additional looting or exploration.

Comment: That's pretty weird actually. But yeah, I can live with that.